# “Dies gilt es zu tun” – tricky punctuation with Infinitivgruppen

Tags: style, punctuation, infinitive

Kommasetzung bei erweiterten Infinitiven ist gemäß irgendwelchen Reformen optional.

Trotzdem setze ich da gerne Kommata. Kopfschmerzen bereitet mir dabei aber das Beispiel

> (A) Dies gilt es zu tun.

Ich möchte nach “gilt” ein Komma setzen, finde aber weder

> (A’) Dies, gilt es, zu tun.

noch

> (A’’) Dies gilt es, zu tun.

wirklich eingängig. Beides ist holprig und letzteres davon holpriger.

Welche der Varianten (A), (A’) und (A’’) ist stilistisch vorzuziehen? Welche dieser Varianten gelten als *grammatikalisch korrekt*?

Comment: Wie kommst du überhaupt auf Fall (A’)?

Comment: @Jan: Ich erkläre es in meiner in Entstehung begriffenen Antwort. :)

Comment: @chirlu Juchu, wieder Gelegenheit, ein Sportsmann zu sein =D

Comment: @Jan Wenn man umstellt, hat man “Es gilt, dies zu tun”, als das Objekt zum Verb, finde ich, “dies” nicht durch ein Komma von “tun” getrennt werden, es sei denn durch zwei. Das “dies” gehört einfach zur Infinitivgruppe dazu. Vergleiche mit Einschüben à la “Dies, denke ich, werde ich tun.”. Ich habe den Titel wieder abgeändert.

Comment: Warum bestehst du auf einem *fremdsprachlichem* Titel bei einer Frage, die *in einem Deutschforum auf Deutsch* gestellt wird?

Comment: @Jan Ja, finden viele merkwürdig: Auf dieser Seite lesen auch Deutsch Lernende. Ich halte es für sinnvoll, die Fragentitel komplett auf Englisch (und informativ) zu halten, sodass man auf jedem Niveau eine ungefähre Vorstellung davon hat, wonach gefragt wird – also auch als blutiger Anfänger. Englisch deshalb, weil die Sprache der Seite selbst Englisch ist, und Englisch de facto derzeit die globale Lingua Franca ist.

Comment: Ich würde Lernende in Gruppen einteilen. Zu einer Gruppe zähle ich die so blutigen Anfänger, die selbst, wenn sie wissen, worum es geht, weil der Titel auf Englisch ist, die Frage trotzdem nicht lesen oder verstehen können, also hilft es ihnen nicht. Die zweite Gruppe ist weit genug um den Fragen*inhalt* zu verstehen – also logischerweise auch den Titel. Die dritte Gruppe traut sich gegebenenfalls auch zu, auf Deutsch zu antworten/zu kommentieren. Auch für die erste Gruppe halte ich einen englischen Titel für nicht hilfreich, weil er gegebenenfalls Erwartungen weckt, die nicht erfüllt werden.

Comment: @k.stm: Hier die Meta-Diskussion zum Mischen von Sprachen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/what-do-we-want-to-do-with-questions-that-mix-languages Ein Argument gegen deinen Ansatz ist, daß man aus dem Titel nicht mehr erkennen kann, in welcher Sprache Frage und Antwort sind; ein Anfänger wird also ggf. zu dieser Frage gelockt, mit der er dann nichts anfangen kann.

Comment: Hier die neue Meta-Diskussion zu Titelsprachen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1043/15318

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zunächst ist die Frage, was hier eigentlich zum Hauptsatz gehört und was zur Infinitivgruppe. Durch Umstellung kann man unter anderem folgende Sätze gewinnen (vorerst ohne Kommata):

> Es gilt dies zu tun.
> Dies zu tun gilt es.
> Gilt es dies zu tun?

Nicht möglich ist dagegen, das *es* wegzulassen:

> *Dies zu tun gilt.

Demnach ist *es* hier weder ein syntaktischer Platzhalter noch ein Korrelat, sondern fester Bestandteil der Wendung *es gilt*, die hier den Hauptsatz bildet. Dagegen ist *dies zu tun* die Infinitivgruppe. Die entscheidende Besonderheit des Ausgangssatzes ist daher die **Verschränkung** von Hauptsatz und Infinitivgruppe: Ein Teil der Gruppe steht vor dem Hauptsatz, ein Teil danach.

Da die Frage Bezug nimmt auf „irgendwelche Reformen“, zunächst ein Blick auf die Rechtschreibung vor der Reform. Hier war dieser Fall eindeutig geregelt:

> **R 107** Der erweiterte Infinitiv mit „zu“ (die Infinitivgruppe, Grundformgruppe) wird gewöhnlich durch Komma abgetrennt.
> … Es steht aber kein Komma, wenn der erweiterte Infinitiv mit dem Hauptsatz verschränkt ist …
> *Diesen Vorgang wollen wir zu erklären versuchen.* (Hauptsatz: Wir wollen versuchen.)
>
> (Duden, Die deutsche Rechtschreibung, 20. Auflage 1991)

Demnach war die korrekte Schreibweise vor der Reform (A), ganz ohne Komma.

Die *Amtliche Regelung* von 2006 dagegen geht auf eine Verschränkung von Hauptsatz und Infinitivgruppe nicht mehr ausdrücklich ein. Nach § 75 gibt es drei Fälle, in denen eine Infinitivgruppe zwingend mit Komma abgegrenzt wird; keiner von diesen Fällen liegt hier vor. Allerdings gibt es noch eine Erlaubnis für weitere Fälle:

> § 75 E2: In den Fällen, die nicht durch § 75 (1) bis (3) geregelt sind, kann ein Komma gesetzt werden, um die Gliederung deutlich zu machen bzw. um Missverständnisse auszuschließen. …

Das ist nun hinreichend vage, um sowohl (A’) als auch (A’’) darunter zu fassen (sofern man „ein Komma“ nicht als „ein Komma, aber nicht mehr!“ auffassen will). Die Symmetrie spräche in diesem Fall dafür, beide Übergänge zwischen Hauptsatz und Infinitivgruppe gleich zu behandeln, also für (A’). Ob dies dienlich ist, *um die Gliederung deutlich zu machen bzw. um Missverständnisse auszuschließen*, oder im Gegenteil sogar hinderlich, liegt im Ermessen des Schreibers.

Comment: Hervorragende Antwort. Anmerkung: Reformen sind mir eigentlich egal, aber es tut gut, zu wissen, was 1991 über verschränkte Infinitivgruppen gedacht worden ist. Das hilft bereits.

Comment: Verdammt, dass das *dies* zum Infinitiv dazugehört, ist mir nicht aufgefallen … Das ändert natürlich alles.